# Are locks still fail safe for Client/Server topology?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, hazelcast

I know that Hazelcast locks are fail safe for embedded topology. As stated in hazelcast documentation 
(http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#lock) :

> ...when a member leaves the cluster, all the locks acquired by that
>   dead member will be removed so that those locks are immediately
>   available for live members...

We can test this behaviour in our embedded topology. When an instance goes does down, all the related locks are successfully released as expected.

Does the same behaviour apply for the Client/Server topology? I.e if a client that acquires a lock goes down, are these locks acquired by the dead client released in the cluster?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the client is just a proxy redirecting commands to the cluster nodes. The behavior will be they same for that very reason. In general client-server architectures are recommended :)

Comment: So I guess this is true for all other behaviors? Since we code against the com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance interface , and it is the same api for both embeded mode ( Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()) and client mode ( HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient()) , we can expect the exact behavior, right? And why do you recommend client-server architecture ? :)

Comment: Yeah this is true, except (unfortunately) some exceptions are slightly different on clients than they are on nodes. This is supposed to be fixed in Hazelcast 4 (at the given time) but stays for backwards compatibility. Anyhow these things are rare. -- we recommend client-server for multiple reasons, better option to optimize gc, clean separation between storage and business logic, independent scalability, ... there are whitepapers :)

Comment: Hi noctarius. Many thanks for the detailed explanation. Could you please provide links to whitepapers? And one last question:  What is the best cluster topology to serve multiple applications in client/server mode? Actually I asked this in a separate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039220/hazelcast-what-is-the-best-cluster-topology-to-serve-multiple-applications-in          Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "best cluster topology"? You probably find the webinar most informative: https://hazelcast.com/resources/whats-new-hazelcast-imdg-3-8/ (can't find the whitepaper right now I was thinking about) :)

Comment: Thanks. An answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039220/hazelcast-what-is-the-best-cluster-topology-to-serve-multiple-applications-in would also be good, though :)